# Mongoose Model does not save referenced model?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, mongodb, mongoose

I am currently trying to set up a backend API with mongo and express, and i am struggling to get a create route to work. This is my route:

```
reservationsRouter.post("/", (req, res) => {
  assert.notEqual(req.body.user, null);
  const user = User.findById(req.body.user);
  const reservation = new Reservation({
    dateStart: req.body.dateStart,
    dateEnd: req.body.dateEnd,
    user: user
  });
  res.json(reservation);
  reservation.save();
});
```

My reservationSchema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ReservationSchema = Schema({
  user: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: "User", required: true },
  dateStart: { type: String, required: true },
  dateEnd: { type: String, required: true }
});

module.exports = ReservationSchema;
```

and my userSchema:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const userSchema = Schema({
  _id: { type: String, required: true },
  firstName: { type: String, required: true },
  lastName: { type: String, required: true },
  reservations: [{ type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Reservation" }]
});

module.exports = userSchema;
```

My problem is, that when i save a reservation and GET all the reservations, it does not have a `user` attribute, even though i have specified it in the schema:

```
{
    "dateStart": "1234",
    "dateEnd": "12345",
    "_id": "5b127d9d3d8256eedd31173b"
}
```

**EDIT:** I have rewritten the route as follows so that the callback returns the reservation with the user, but still, when i GET all the reservations, the User is not included as in the example above.

```
reservationsRouter.post("/", (req, res) => {
  assert.notEqual(req.body.user, null);
  const user = User.findById(req.body.user, (err, user) => {
    if (err) res.send(err);
    else {
      const reservation = new Reservation({
        dateStart: req.body.dateStart,
        dateEnd: req.body.dateEnd,
        user: user
      });
      res.json(reservation);
      reservation.save();
    }
  });
});
```

You might want to check out the entire repo: https://github.com/SchulenbergOrg/backend/tree/mongo

Comment: `const user = User.findById(req.body.user);` does not actually return the `user`. [Read the duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) and understand why.

Comment: I don't know how that question relates to mine to be honest. I am using callbacks, not promises.

Comment: Talks about both. And you "did not use a callback" which is exactly the point.

Comment: Read the very good reference answer you have already been pointed to. You clearly don't understand how to do this properly or which functions here are actually async. Everything the `findBy` the `save()` that touches the database is "async" and you need to await the result. Please read as it's how you actually learn and will show you what to do.